# make IIS 7.5 cache static content files over diferent pages

Tags: iis-7.5, cache

On a Windows 2008 R2, using DNS and IIS I've established my development test server; i.e. I'll have a web application that I can browse on http://test.dev

I've moved all the static content files like images, js files and css files into another application which is visible on http://cdn.test.dev

test.dev, uses cdn.test.dev urls like http://cdn.test.dev/js/jquery.js to load js, css and images.

When I first load "~/" of test.dev, all files will load with a response code of 200; when I press F5 in Firefox, all files, except the "~/default.aspx", will load with 304 response code; but pressing Ctrl+F5 loads them again with a 200 code; if I browse another url like "~/pages/" in test.dev, all of those static files will reload with a 200 code... *Is this normal or I'm doing something **wrong**?*

**Actually, I'm looking for a behavior like this:**
I want the client to load http://cdn.test.dev/js/jquery.js, only once. I want the client's browser to use this jquery.js file, from cache, in all other pages of test.dev

**Is this possible**?

This is the web.config file I have in the root directory of cdn.test.dev:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <caching>
            <profiles>
                <add extension=".png" policy="CacheUntilChange" varyByHeaders="User-Agent" location="Client" />
                <add extension=".gif" policy="CacheUntilChange" varyByHeaders="User-Agent" location="Client" />
                <add extension=".jpg" policy="CacheUntilChange" varyByHeaders="User-Agent" location="Client" />
                <add extension=".js" policy="CacheUntilChange" varyByHeaders="User-Agent" location="Client" />
                <add extension=".css" policy="CacheUntilChange" varyByHeaders="User-Agent" location="Client" />
                <add extension=".axd" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" varyByHeaders="User-Agent" location="Client" />
            </profiles>
        </caching>
        <httpProtocol allowKeepAlive="true">
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="Cache-Control" value="public, max-age=31536000" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
            <remove name="RadUploadModule" />
            <remove name="RadCompression" />
            <add name="RadUploadModule" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadHttpModule" preCondition="integratedMode" />
            <add name="RadCompression" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadCompression" preCondition="integratedMode" />
        </modules>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="ChartImage_axd" />
            <remove name="Telerik_Web_UI_SpellCheckHandler_axd" />
            <remove name="Telerik_Web_UI_DialogHandler_aspx" />
            <remove name="Telerik_RadUploadProgressHandler_ashx" />
            <remove name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd" />
            <add name="ChartImage_axd" path="ChartImage.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" />
            <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_SpellCheckHandler_axd" path="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" />
            <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_DialogHandler_aspx" path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" />
            <add name="Telerik_RadUploadProgressHandler_ashx" path="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadProgressHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" />
            <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" />
        </handlers>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="10485760" />
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
        <staticContent>
           <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseExpires" httpExpires="Wed, 01 Jan 2020 00:00:00 GMT"/>
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
    <appSettings />
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0" />
        <pages>
            <controls>
                <add tagPrefix="telerik" namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" />
            </controls>
        </pages>
        <httpHandlers>
            <add path="ChartImage.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler" verb="*" validate="false" />
            <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler" verb="*" validate="false" />
            <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler" verb="*" validate="false" />
            <add path="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadProgressHandler" verb="*" validate="false" />
            <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" verb="*" validate="false" />
        </httpHandlers>
        <httpModules>
            <add name="RadUploadModule" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadHttpModule" />
            <add name="RadCompression" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadCompression" />
        </httpModules>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="10240" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

and this is the resulting response header for http://cdn.test.dev/css/global.css:

> **Cache-Control:** private,public, max-age=31536000
>   **Content-Type:** text/css
>   **Content-Encoding:** gzip
>   **Expires:** Wed, 01 Jan 2020 00:00:00 GMT
>   **Last-Modified:** Mon, 06 Sep 2010 08:53:06 GMT
>   **Accept-Ranges:** bytes
>   **Etag:** "0454eca04dcb1:0"
>   **Vary:** Accept-Encoding
>   **Server:** Microsoft-IIS/7.5
>   **X-Powered-By:** ASP.NET
>   **Date:** Mon, 06 Sep 2010 14:57:08 GMT
>   **Content-Length:** 4495

Answer (score 1):

> When I first load "~/" of test.dev,
>   all files will load with a response
>   code of 200; when I press F5 in
>   Firefox, all files, except the
>   "~/default.aspx", will load with 304
>   response code; but pressing Ctrl+F5
>   loads them again with a 200 code; if I
>   browse another url like "~/pages/" in
>   test.dev, all of those static files
>   will reload with a 200 code... Is this
>   normal or I'm doing something wrong?

In firefox (and most other browsers) shift+F5 reloads the site ignoring the cache.

Comment: You mean Ctrl+F5 actually. Yes, it's like what you're talking about. but what if I want it to store a styles.css and use that cached stored file, shared between different pages inside a domain?